# How to pass multiple form parameter in "th:action" using themleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I am trying to pass parameter in `th:action`

```
<form class="form-inline" th:object="${search}" method="get" action="search.html" th:action="@{'/hotels/'+${search.location}+'/'+${search.adults}+'/'+${search.dateCheckOut}+'/'+${search.dateCheckIn}}"  id="search-hotel-form">

    <select class="selectpicker form-control input-lt" th:field="*{location}" id="city">
        <option value="delhi">Delhi</option>
    </select>

    <input type='text' th:field="*{dateCheckIn}" id="datetimepicker1" />

    <input type='text' th:field="*{dateCheckOut}" id="datetimepicker2" />

</form>
```

then Spring MVC contoller part

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hotelsparam/{dateCheckIn}/{dateCheckOut}/{location}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView searchHotel(@PathVariable("dateCheckOut") Date dateCheckOut, @PathVariable("dateCheckIn") Date dateCheckIn,@PathVariable("location") String location, BindingResult bindingResult) throws ParseException {....
    //remove implemntation to make it precise
}
```

but getting error is

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "null"
```

URL Part seem like this

```
http://localhost:8080/hotels/null/0/null/null?location=delhi&dateCheckIn=04%2F07%2F2015+09%3A00&dateCheckOut=04%2F07%2F2015+20%3A00&adults=1
```

Comment: Hi Sanchit, please check how are you working between pathvariables, form submitting (and method used) and working with @ModelAttribute in your spring controller, I suggest to start working with some example application, as could be: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/petclinic.html

Comment: Hi Patrick, I am able to solve this issue , basically it was issue with path structure which getting null on call(http://localhost:8080/hotels/null/0/null/null)  thank you :-)